# node.js on windows: add package from build *.node

Tags: node.js

There is a package for node.js (contextify.js) that can not be installed on windows with npm install, because its need to be build. But threre is build version for the package (contextify.node). How should I install in my app (system).

Comment: Are you sure it can be install on Windows..? Is it really compatible?

Comment: https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/10 there is a build for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. goto https://github.com/Benvie/contextify
2. click on the zip link and download the entire archive
3. right click on compter in the start menu click properties
4. Click on advance system settings
5. Click on Environment variables
6. open the path varible and find the path ending in \npm
7. add a new varible called NODE_PATH and give it the value you found in step 6 and append '\node_modules'
8. save and close out of the settings
9. in a cmd line type 'cd %node_path%' it should open the path from step 7 [xxx]\npm\node_modules
10. type 'mkdir contextify'
11. open the zip file from step 2 browse to the \build\release folder
12. copy contextify.node to the contextify folder you just created
13. in the cmd line type 'npm view contextify version'
14. you should see 0.0.7

Done.

Comment: it worked for me, but what dows it means? why the original installation through npm install contextify fails on Windows?

Comment: There is no more \build\release folder in github. Any suggestion?